# Image not loading in web page and says 404 error

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am using tomcat8 application server for my spring project.

I just copy the war from eclipse to tomcat webapps.

Then started my server from terminal. Now the war extracted as a folder as my project name.

If I change the texts in jsp in that folder, it successfully reflects in browser.
When I used a image, which copied into the images folder and access it from jsp, browser not shows that image.

In console I am getting 404 error for this image.

What I need to do now, I need to create a war again from eclipse with this image and paste again?

Comment: Perhaps a permission error on the images?

Comment: No, It says the image is not found..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and the solution is very silly.

It was due to cache problem. When I cleared cache in my browser it is loading fine.